# Automate mount datadrive in azure vm

Tags: azure, automation, jenkins-pipeline, mount, infrastructure

I am able to spin up a (Ubuntu)vm in azure, adding datadisk by terraform and then i need to mount the added datadisk in the azure vm through automation(either jenkins pipeline or powershell) and as well as i need change docker directory through automation. Can anyone help me please.

I tried to automate the manual steps for mount datadrive , but i am not able to mount it -facing issues while executing below commands. I am not able to execute below commands in single line

**sudo parted /dev/sdc**

I am not able to copy value after executing below command and paste it in `/etc/fstab`

**sudo -i blkid**

Automate all below commands

```
**dmesg | grep SCSI
sudo parted /dev/sdc
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
sudo mkdir /datadrive
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive
sudo -i blkid
sudo vi /etc/fstab**
```

I need to automate all above commands through jenkins pipeline or powershell.
I am trying automate infrastructure i got stucked at this point.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: For automation, I think you need some commands without interact. Take a look at [parttition in a single line](https://serverfault.com/questions/258152/fdisk-partition-in-single-line)

Comment: @MohanKanth how are you able to achieve the copy pasting of UUID value in `fstab` file during automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below commands are working fine.

```
dmesg | grep SCSI
echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw" | fdisk /dev/sdc
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
sudo mkdir /datadrive
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive
```